# Images are not displaying from specific URL's in windows app

Tags: angularjs, windows, mobile

I have developed Hybrid app using Ionic(Angular) and trying to display image in image tag, folllowing is the code.

```
<ion-content>
   <img ng-src="{{product.ProductMediaItems[0].MediaSrcURL}}" Width="100%">
</ion-content>
```

In dom element image tag looks following -

```
<img src="https://modpizza.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/whats-your-mod.png" Width="100%">
```

Issue -

**Image is not displaying in windows app,** while it is working in Android and IOS.

If I try to change the image url and to some other website image path after inspecting the app in visual studio image is loading fine.

Not sure it is a issue with particular website "https://modpizza.com/" or Ionic with windows app.

Comment: Difficult to say for sure, but I know has been a known issue in Ionic (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-view-issues/issues/54). Is the original MediaSrcUrl a local path? Might explain why other paths work. Try to hard code the absolute url in your ngSrc to make sure.

Comment: @zilj, Thanks for reply.
It is a original MediaSrcUrl not a local path.
I tried to hard code url even from website "https://modpizza.com/" not getting the image.
From other website say "amazon" it works.